# Is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS support Nvidia Graphics Driver 390.48?

Tags: drivers, lightdm, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-settings

After a successful installation of NVIDIA Graphics Driver 390.48 (all step for example blacklist nouveau and close the service of lightdm I have all already done), then I test whether NVIDIA Driver work properly, I input `nvidia-smi`  and `nvidia-settings`. However the result is weird, `nvidia-smi` works properly, it print the info of my driver on screen, however `nvidia-settings` give a message that it can not connect to NVIDIA driver.

And when I enable the lightdm service and reboot. The screen become blank except a cursor in the left up corner of the screen.

I wonder if Ubuntu 18.04 LTS does not support the latest version of NVIDIA Driver.

Is that true? If that is true, what is the latest version that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS support. If that is false, what can I do?

I'm sorry that I can not upload a screenshot because without the lightdm service, it is impossible for me to make a screenshot.

Comment: I have no problems with 390.48 on a Quadro 1000M using gdm.  What video hardware do you have?  Is a later Nvidia driver version offered, like 396?

Comment: @ubfan1, GTX1050 Mobile with lightdm.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can upgrade to a newer NVIDIA version on Ubuntu 18.04.

To do this, you would add the graphics driver PPA with the following commands in terminal:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update`

After this, you should now remove any current NVIDIA drivers by entering the following into your terminal:

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`

Now that you have done this, it is safe to install the latest version:

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-396`

Please note that it is nvidia-driver-396 on Ubuntu 18.04, it is nvidia-396 on Ubuntu 16.04 but you are not using 16.04.